# Print only the characters below a specific word in a line

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to write a script that does two different things: it picks a random word and causes it to "jump" out of a line, and it also "turns" on a word. By turn, I mean it picks a random word and then only prints the same number of characters from that word beneath it, and nothing else, like so:

```
this is a thing that I am typing
          sdfas
          wertq
          wsvsd
          swefs
```

This is what I mean by making it "jump" out of the line:

```
          thing
this is a       that I am typing
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to say "print the [x] number of characters under x"

Here is my code, below:

```
import random
import sys

s = open('sonnets.txt')

counting = 0

for line in s:
    line.strip()
    randomInt = random.randint(1,100)
    counting = counting+1
    words = line.split()
    test = 1
    if (randomInt < 2*counting):
        if (len(words) > 0):
            r = random.choice(words)
            if r in line:
                ind = line.index(r)
                wordChoice = len(r)
                print ((" " * (ind))+r).upper()
                whiteSpace = wordChoice+2
                newLine = line.replace(r, (" " * whiteSpace))
                print newLine
            turn = random.choice(words)
            if turn in line:
                turnCheck = True 
                ind = line.index(turn)
                wordChoice = len(turn)
                print ((" " * (ind))+turn)
                foo = line[ind:ind+4]
                print ((" " * (ind))+foo)   
    else:
        print line
```

The above code runs, but only succeeds in making the text "jump". Can anyone help with creating this column of words?

Again, any help you could give would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier in both cases just to find the index in the char array of the first character of the word you want to perform the action on? Then you can simply print a new line with " " up to the index and print the random characters

Comment: This question would be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I didn't know that existed, thanks! I will post it over there.

Answer (score 0):

```
txt='this is a thing that I am typing'

jumpword='thing'
jumpind=txt.find(jumpword)
newtxt=str(txt)
if jumpind>=0:
    newtxt=newtxt.replace(jumpword," "*len(jumpword),1)
    newtxt=" "*jumpind+jumpword+'\n'+newtxt 
print newtxt
```

Result:

```
          thing
this is a       that I am typing
```

The word turning:

```
import random
def randword(length,sourcelist):
    # get random word: (move this out of the function if you need to keep it the same)
    rword=random.sample(sourcelist,1)[0]
    # get length number of letters from it.
    return "".join(map(lambda dummy:random.sample(rword,1)[0],range(length)))

print txt
# make 5 turns:
for i in range(5):
    print " "*jumpind+randword(len(jumpword),txt.split())
```

Result:

```
this is a thing that I am typing
          IIIII
          aaaaa
          IIIII
          yngtt
          hthti
```